# SQL Server Query - Which is better in performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

I think query 1 is more readable than query 2, but I'd like to know if there is any difference between them in terms of performance?

Query 1

```
UPDATE table_1
SET col_1 = 
      CASE WHEN table_1.col_pk IS NULL THEN value1
           ELSE value2
      END
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.col_pk = table_2.col_pk
```

or

Query 2

```
UPDATE table_1
SET col_1 = value1
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.col_pk = table_2.col_pk
WHERE table_1.col_pk IS NULL

UPDATE table_1
SET col_1 = value2
FROM table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.col_pk = table_2.col_pk
```

Comment: benchmark...........

Comment: `CASE WHEN col_pk IS NULL` which of two `col_pk`?

Comment: oops sorry.. table_1.col_pk instead. Thanks. I will update the thread.

Comment: In the first query, I don't think `table_1.col_pk IS NULL` is ever true if it's a PK and you take it as the left part in a `LEFT JOIN`. You probably meant to write `table_2.col_pk IS NULL` there?

Comment: Ow you're correct. Sorry.. edit again.. hehehhehe. But I know that you already get my point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first query will probably have better performance because it requires only a single scan of `table_1` and `table_2`.

Comment: Appreciated. Btw, in case of setting the value? Query 1 will set the value conditionally, so it will first check the col_pk before the assignment of proper value.

Comment: Yes, but that operation is typically less work than scanning and joining tables.

Comment: Thanks mendosi. I have more questions in my mind but then let me create another thread instead, since it will take different topic. Thanks again.